# How to pull a substring off a string without knowing what the string is (file path)

Tags: python

I have a given file path. For example, `"C:\Users\cobyk\Downloads\GrassyPath.jpg"`. I would like to pull in a separate string, the image file name.

I'm assuming the best way to do that is to start from the back end of the string, find the final slash and then take the characters following that slash. Is there a method to do this already or will I have search through the string via a for loop, find the last slash myself, and then do the transferring manually?

Comment: Why not just use `os.path.basename()` to get the filename?

Comment: Are you saying in a complicated way that you want the base file name?  `os.path.basename(s)` is designed for that task.

Comment: You could do something like

```
import os
s = '/Users/cobyk/Downloads/GrassyPath.jpg'
print(os.path.basename(s))
```

Note: tested this on a mac so the slashes are the wrong direction for you, but it you put in your file path on windows it should work the same.

Comment: It is a little known fact that ALL Windows APIs accept either forward slashes or backward slashes.  It's only the command shell that insists on backslashes.

Comment: @Tim: And that's pertinent because…?

Comment: `os.path` is sooo ancient, for new code I highly recommend using the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module that was added in Python 3.4 (which was released 2014-03-16).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly search manually as you've suggested.  However, the Python standard library already has, as you suspected, a function which does this for you.

```py
import os

file_name = os.path.basename(r'C:\Users\cobyk\Downloads\GrassyPath.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) module makes it very easy to [access individual parts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#accessing-individual-parts) of a file path like the [final path component](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name):

```
from pathlib import Path

image_path = Path(r"C:\Users\cobyk\Downloads\GrassyPath.jpg")
print(image_path.name)  # -> GrassyPath.jpg
```